# Login at two wordpress blogs at once

Tags: php, wordpress, authentication

I'm stumbling into a little problem as I'm currently trying to programmatically log into two wordpress blogs at once. I have a custom login page and the sessions for both wordpress blogs have to be created. One blog works just fine, but as I have to include another `wp-load.php` it doesn't work for the second one... My code so far:

```
...
public static function blogLogin($mail, $password) {
        require __DIR__ . '/../blog/wp-load.php';

        $wpuser = get_user_by('email', $mail);
        if (!$wpuser) $wpuser = get_user_by('login', $mail);

        if (!empty($wpuser) && !empty($wpuser->ID)) {
            wp_set_auth_cookie($wpuser->ID, true);
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
}

public static function secondBlogLogin($mail, $password) {
        require __DIR__ . '/../secondblog/wp-load.php';

        $wpuser = get_user_by('email', $mail);
        if (!$wpuser) $wpuser = get_user_by('login', $mail);

        if (!empty($wpuser) && !empty($wpuser->ID)) {
            wp_set_auth_cookie($wpuser->ID, true);
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
}
...
```

And is being called by:
`Class::blogLogin(...); Class::secondBlogLogin(...);`
This seems not to work as the include is not only "sandboxed" inside the function but also available in the outside. Is there a ways to either kind off an inclusion or otherwise to achieve this login at both wordpress blogs in one script?

Comment: Not sure if this what you wanna achieve have a look here : https://infinitewp.com/

Comment: This seems to be only for adminstration logins, I am looking for a solution for all users (authors and users). One login form starts a main session + blog 1 and blog 2 sessions.

Comment: ok, try check here maybe it can point u to right direction http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/131399/share-login-data-cookies-between-multiple-installations 

I'm not tht in to wp

Comment: Thanks, this looks correct, but somehow isn't working either 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below answer is for enable login of two word press during one execution from single custom login page.

```
//Your form which contain custom login (email,password).

<?php
//afer submit form post login credential value into PHP code of first file.
if(isset($_POST) && isset($_POST['submit'])){       
require("path of first wordpress root directory \wp-load.php");
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
    $user = wp_get_current_user();
} else {
    $creds = array();
    // Use the submited information to populate the user_login & user_password
    $creds['user_login']    = $_POST['username or email'];
    $creds['user_password'] = $_POST['password'];
    $creds['remember']      = true;
    $user                   = wp_signon( $creds, false );
    if ( is_wp_error( $user ) ) {
        echo $user->get_error_message();
    } else {
        wp_set_auth_cookie( $user->ID, true );
    }
    ?>    
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var url = 'url/first-blog-login.php';      
    var user = '<?php echo $_POST['username or email'];?>';
    var password = '<?php echo $_POST['password'];?>';
    $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: url,
       data: {
           'user':user,
           'password':password
       },
       success: function(){         
          alert("detail passed successfully.");
       }
     });       
    </script>
    <?php
}
}   

if(isset($_POST) && !empty($_POST)){
    $user =  $_POST['user'];
  $password =  $_POST['password'];
  require("path of secound wordpress root directory\wp-load.php");
  if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
    $user = wp_get_current_user();
} else {
    $creds= array();
    // Use the submited information to populate the user_login & user_password
    $creds['user_login']    = $user;
    $creds['user_password'] = $password;
    $creds['remember']      = true;
    $user                   = wp_signon( $creds, false );
    if ( is_wp_error( $user ) ) {
        echo $user->get_error_message();
    } else {
        wp_set_auth_cookie( $user->ID, true );
    }
}
}
?>
```

Comment: Still not a PHP-only solution, I've also thought about an AJAX request, but you're right this is definitely working more comfortable as it doesn't have a redirect. And probably the only way to get this done properly. Thanks for your effort!

Answer (score 1):

Here programmatically log into two wordpress blogs at once,

Below code may fulfil your requirement.

It need two php file for enable cookies for two wordpress

Place below code into your **first PHP file**:

**e.g. www/folder/first-blog-login.php**

```
//Your form which contain custom login (email,password).

<?php
//afer submit form post login credential value into PHP code of first file.
if(isset($_POST) && isset($_POST['submit'])){       
require("path of first wordpress root directory \wp-load.php");
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
    $user = wp_get_current_user();
} else {
    $creds = array();
    // Use the submited information to populate the user_login & user_password
    $creds['user_login']    = $_POST['username or email'];
    $creds['user_password'] = $_POST['password'];
    $creds['remember']      = true;
    $user                   = wp_signon( $creds, false );
    if ( is_wp_error( $user ) ) {
        echo $user->get_error_message();
    } else {
        wp_set_auth_cookie( $user->ID, true );
    }
    ?>
    <script>
    var url = 'www/folder/secound-blog-login.php';      
    document.cookie="user=<?php echo $_POST['username'];?>";
    document.cookie="password=<?php echo $_POST['password'];?>";
    window.open(url, "_blank");
    window.open('','_self').close()
    </script>
    <?php
}
}   
?>
```

Place below code into your **secound PHP file**:

**e.g. www/folder/secound-blog-login.php**

```
<?php
  $user =  $_COOKIE['user'];
  $password =  $_COOKIE['password'];
  require("path of secound wordpress root directory\wp-load.php");
  if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
    $user = wp_get_current_user();
} else {
    $creds= array();
    // Use the submited information to populate the user_login & user_password
    $creds['user_login']    = $user;
    $creds['user_password'] = $password;
    $creds['remember']      = true;
    $user                   = wp_signon( $creds, false );
    if ( is_wp_error( $user ) ) {
        echo $user->get_error_message();
    } else {
        wp_set_auth_cookie( $user->ID, true );
    }
}
//Your further code for execution.
?>
```

You can encode / decode login credential while sending to new window.

Hope it will help you!!!

Comment: Thanks for you answer, this is indeed working - and pretty similar to what I did as a workaround as well (I made a redirect with an auto submitting form - which is a bit more secure than storing the password unencrypted in a cookie) but as mentioned above I'm actually looking for a solution without a redirect...

Comment: Please check my another answer in which i have been using one file and after first login of wordpress i am calling ajax for another wordpress login during one execution.I am  posting another answer as different method.Hope it will help you out as well.